# WARNING: Array to string conversion in C:/Path-of-my-website/prispevky/photos.php on line 150

Tags: php

i have on line 150..

```
$sql = "UPDATE " . TABLEP . " SET alt='$_POST[alt]', text='$_POST[text]', nadpis='$_POST[nadpis]', datum='$_POST'datum', odkaz='$_POST[odkaz]', urltext='$_POST[urltext]' WHERE id = " . $_GET["edit"];
```

Please help

Answer (score -1):

Here's your problem: `datum='$_POST'datum'`. You forgot to add the brackets.

Comment: there is much more wrong he mixes GEt with POST and this is the basis if his problem one of them must be NULL  also TABLEP  should be $TABLEP  and even more, besides sql injection

Comment: @nbk `$_GET` and `$_POST` can be mixed just fine - HTTP requests can have both a query string and a body. TABLEP could also be a constant. The issue here is with the missing brackets (though SQL injection is also definitely a problem).

Comment: @nbk, I was addressing _only_ the issue that OP has mentioned. Of course the code is wrong on many levels.